# Developing ms crm 2011 plugin on vs 2015

Tags: c#, plugins, visual-studio-2015, dynamics-crm-2011

How can I develop a custom plugin for MS CRM 2011 using MS Visual Studio 2015?
The problem is that plugin development requires CRM SDK to be installed on VS, but it is impossible to install CRM SDK 2011 on VS 2015 (it errors with 'you should install visual studio first'), as I can understand it looks for VS 2010.

Also, I haven't found a way to install CRM SDK 2015 on VS 2015, as I figured out Microsoft separated out these two things.

I don't want to buy VS 2010 additionally, and I can't change company politics of using MS CRM 2011.

Comment: Is there only way to add required dlls as reference to my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Software Development Kit (SDK)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=24004).

Then run the executable, all it does is extract files to a folder directory (not sure where the Visual Studio link comes in here).

You can find the CRM assemblies in the SDK\Bin folder, you can then add the references directly to your project.

Alternatively you could try [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSDCRM2011SDK/) to simply get the references.